# Is there a way to match duplicate characters without lookarounds?

Tags: regex, google-docs, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to reduce duplicate characters down to 1 in a cell: `abbbbbbbc` to `abc`. It would seem simple with regexreplace, but it appears that Google docs does not deal in lookarounds. Here's a simplified version of my formula

```
=regexreplace("abbbbc","(.)\1+", "$1")
```

The regex works in regex hero, but not in google docs, and I've tracked it down to the `\1`. I'm not an expert in regex, so I'd like to know if there's a way to do this without referring to the group to get the duplicates.

Since this is for a public thing, here's the doc in question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iPRTFoJvbWlKftvq3cZCiDRCnws5viwEJCiTRSL9zps/edit?usp=sharing

The problem formula is in the A column on the Derivations sheet.

Comment: Do you must use regex? Regex is slow. I know, how to do using own method.

Comment: @barwnikk: only bad patterns are slow, not regex.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you following me? haha

Comment: Are you sure about the replace term? Some engines use `\1` instead of `$1`. Try that. Your regex looks OK btw

Comment: @barwnikk I don't have to use regex, but I don't know of another way in Google Docs that'll work for a large number of cells. I don't want to have to build a whole sheet around doing this one time, it's for a large word list.

Comment: @Bohemian I tried that, but it doesn't work; ``(.)$1+`` appears valid, but it doesn't catch the duplicate for some reason.

Comment: I meant using `\1` in the replace term, not the search term

Comment: Sorry, okay, I tried that too, but the error is specifically telling me that `(.)\1+` is invalid, the second parameter of the function.

Comment: Google docs does not support backreferences. It uses google re2 which has the syntax https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt. Search for `backreference` in that document to see "NOT SUPPORTED"